# Removing join-table record by attribute of opposite table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have User:

```
has_many :user_artists
has_many :artists, :through => :user_artists
```

UserArtist:

```
belongs_to :artist
belongs_to :user
delegate :itunes_id, :to => :artist
```

Artist

```
has_many :user_artists
has_many :users, :through => :user_artists
attr_accessible :itunes_id
```

I want to destroy a given user's user_artists based on a given itunes_id for that artist. I can do `User.first.user_artists.select {|ua| ua.itunes_id == 200823564}` but is there a way to do it just using ActiveRecord? Or is this the most efficient way?

I was thinking something like `User.first.user_artists.where( :artist => {:itunes_id => 1000}).destroy_all` but SQL complains that there isn't a artist.itunes_id column on user_artists.

Comment: I am curious why you're not using a simple join table (`:has_and_belongs_to_many`) users have many artists and artists have many users.  The join table (which should be may named in alpha order `artists_users`) doesn't appear to do anything other than join, which is the [rule described here for choosing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many).  Look into `:dependent_destroy` with a lamba to scope only to specific itunes ids.  This should definitely be something AR can do cleanly and simply.

Comment: aha! It was the alphabetic part that got me. I tried that and it kept complaining about not finding artist_users even though I had user_artists. Thanks, I'll change it back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
User.first.user_artists.join(:artist).where('artist.itunes_id = ?', 1000).destroy_all
```

Comment: This works for my situation. Future readers should also look at the first question comment, because I wasn't taking advantage of HABTM.

Comment: @Chris just to be clear: HABTM is just a shortcut, and should be used only if you are sure you will not store any additional information in the linking table. If there are any doubts, you should use has_many => through as you did